# How to restore Ubuntu desktop/GUI to previous appearance?

Tags: 16.04, unity, evolution, geary

After installing the Evolution and Geary e-mail clients, Ubuntu desktop and application GUIs are messed up. See screenshot below for an example; as you can see, tabs are not separated anymore, and buttons (Revert, Close) are not drawn.

How can I restore the previous desktop/GUI appearance, without re-installing Ubuntu?

Things I have tried:

- purge Evolution and Geary
- purge and reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` (from console, CTRL+ALT+F1)
- purge and reinstall `unity` (from console, CTRL+ALT+F1)
- `rm  -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1`

Running Ubuntu 16.04 with its default desktop.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### On Ubuntu 18.04 +

##### Gnome Tweaks

This method will reset all the themes, icons, etc.

1. First, install Gnome Tweaks:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```
2. Then launch gnome tweaks:

   ```
   gnome-tweaks
   ```
3. Then navigate to *Appearance → Then application theme → Yaru → Icon theme → Yaru and everything to YARU or Adwaita*.

You can also check the title bar group and other groups to find other settings

##### Dconf editor.

This method will **remove all configurations**. Use with caution!

1. Install dconf editor:

   ```
   sudo apt install dconf-editor
   ```

   The above command will fetch almost 3MB of archives.
2. To reset everything, run:

   ```
   sudo dconf reset -f /
   ```

---

##### Manually resetting.

You can use the dconf editor to manually reset selected things.

1. Run the dconf-editor:

   ```
   sudo dconf-editor
   ```
2. Navigate to `/org/gnome` (or any other path).
3. Right-click on the desired setting.
4. Select reset.
5. Click the bottom check-mark button.

---

**Note**: I would recommend doing all the above commands in a Virtual terminal instead of GUI.